# Идея по выводу переменной из цикла

Tags: php

Мой вопрос заключается в том, чтоб из цикла `foreach` вывести переменную `marks` в массив `dataPoints` в отметки `здесь`

```
$user_marks = $user->ownMarksList;

foreach ($user_marks as $mark) {
  $marks = $mark['usersmark'];
  echo $marks;
}

$dataPoints = array(
  array("x" => 1, "y" => `здесь`),
  array("x" => 2, "y" => `здесь`),
  array("x" => 3, "y" => `здесь`),
  array("x" => 4, "y" => `здесь`),
  array("x" => 5, "y" => `здесь`),
);
```

Друзья программисты, какие есть идеи?

Comment: Сколько у вас записей в массиве `$user_marks`, по какому принципу они должны заноситься в массив `$dataPoints`?

Comment: в цикле: `$marks[]['y'] = $mark['usersmark'];`, за циклом: `$dataPoints = array_replace_recursive($dataPoints,$marks);`

Comment: Благодарю user-2147482225 за быстрый и точный ответ, который смог и помог